# LINQ Group by of Nested object value and repeat Parent object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complex object coming back from an API call. For brevity:

```
Foo { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
Bar { 
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

What I need to do is group `Foo` by all the repeating `Bars`. `Foo` will likely be duplicated over and over, and this is the desired behavior. So, if the return is:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Bars: [{
            name: "Johnson",
        },{
            name: "Johnson",
        },{
            name: "Johnson",
        },{
            name: "Cedric",
        },{
            name: "Cedric",
        },
    ]
}
```

My Linq query needs to result in:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Bars: [{
            name: "Johnson",
        },{
            name: "Johnson",
        },{
            name: "Johnson",
        },
    ]
},    {
    Id: 1,
    Bars: [{
            name: "Cedric",
        },{
            name: "Cedric",
        }
    ]
},
```

I've been playing around with variations of:

```
foos.SelectMany(f => f.Bars.Select(b => new { Foo = f, Bar = b })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Bar);
```

But can't seem to get it exactly where I need to. The `Bar` object does contain other properties, as well as another nested object. Any direction on what this may be called (if anything), or how to achieve the results I'm looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a list of `Foo`, if I am not mistaken? So this would do it?

```
var foo = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Bars = new List<Bar>()
    {
        new Bar() { Name = "Johnson" },
        new Bar() { Name = "Johnson" },
        new Bar() { Name = "Johnson" },
        new Bar() { Name = "Cedric" },
        new Bar() { Name = "Cedric" }
    }
};

var results = new List<Foo>();
var groups = foo.Bars.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    results.Add(new Foo() { Id = foo.Id, Bars = group.Select(x => x).ToList() });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to group by Foo.Id and Bar.Name so the following should give you the result you are looking for:

```
foos
    // Get the Foo, Bar pairs
    .SelectMany(f => f.Bars.Select(b => new { Foo = f, Bar = b })
    // Group them by Foo.Id, Bar.Name
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Foo.Id, x.Bar.Name })
    // Get the pairs of Foo.Id and list of Bar.Name
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Bars = x.Select(y => y.Name) //.ToArray() if you want an array
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One line LINQ solution, assuming you have a single foo object with a list of bars in,  after applying the group query, you will get the list of foos based on bar name grouping:

```
List<Foo> foos = foo.Bars.GroupBy(b => b.Name).Select(g => new Foo() { Id = foo.Id, Bars = g.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                List<Foo> foo = new List<Foo>() {
                        new Foo() {
                            Id = 1,
                            Bars = new List<Bar>() {
                                new Bar() { Name = "Johnson"},
                                new Bar() { Name = "Johnson"},
                                new Bar() { Name = "Johnson"},
                                new Bar() { Name = "Cederic"},
                                new Bar() { Name = "Cederic"}
                            }
                        }
                };

                var foos = foo.SelectMany(x => x.Bars.Select(y => new { Id = x.Id, Name = y.Name }).ToList());

                List<Foo> results = foos.GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
                    .Select(x => new Foo() { Id = x.Key.Id, Bars = x.Select(y => new Bar() { Name = y.Name }).ToList() })
                    .ToList();
            }

        }
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    }
    public class Bar
    {
        public string Name { get;set;}
    }
```